# How can I host a wordpress blog with laravel 5

Tags: wordpress, laravel-5

I am building a laravel 5.3 website for a client. he asked me to host a wordpress blog with this. if i host a wordpress blog on same hosting an assign a subdomain to it then it is easy as site address is `abc.com` and blog address will be `blog.abc.com`. but he asked me that he want blog with this `abc.com/blog` address. and i dont know how can I full fill his wish. can somebody help me please.?? to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution would be to host it on a sub domain to prevent routing issues. But if the requirement is that you have it under the main domain folder you can do it. You need to make changes to the rewrite rules to ignore the folder `blog`, so that it doesn't route it to laravel. You need to modify the `.htaccess` file if you're on apache or the ngnix domain conf file.